# DyGraphs time period option

Tags: dygraphs

I'm hoping someone has come across this. Does anyone know of a way to add time period links on DyGraphs?  Something similar to this example https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTa7c.png

I've searched but I can find an example. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the first column of your data are proper dates, I think the key is the `dateWindow()` option.

Something like this maybe?

```js
<div class="configDivClass">
    <button onclick='selectLast24hours(24)'>
        Previous 24 hours
    </button>
    <button onclick='selectLast24hours(36)'>
        Previous 48 hours
    </button>
    <button onclick='selectLast24hours(72)'>
        Previous 72 hours
    </button>
</div>
```

And then the js:

```js
function selectLast24hours(hours) {
    var range = g.xAxisRange();
    var maxX = range[1];
    var minX = maxX - hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    g.updateOptions(
    {
        dateWindow: [minX, maxX],
    });
}
```